# Azure Application Insights is marking response code zero as success

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-application-insights

Recently we encountered an issue where our servers times out because of huge traffic surge, and those request telemetries were logged into AI as success with response code zero. Is there any way to configure response code zero to be termed as failure. Since request telemetries are captured automatically by AI so we dont have any handle on that

Comment: Is it a .NET project(.net core or .NET framework), or other project?

Comment: .net core project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by using [ITelemetryInitializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#addmodify-properties-itelemetryinitializer) in your .NET core project.

To be termed as failure when response code is zero, you can set the `Success` property of request telemetry data as `false`. The sample code as below(using .NET core 2.2 for this test). And please make sure you're using the latest version of [Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore 2.13.1.](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore)

Here is the custom ITelemetryInitializer:

```
public class MyTelemetryInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
{
    public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        if (telemetry is RequestTelemetry)
        {
            var requestTelemetry = telemetry as RequestTelemetry;

            //you can change the ResponseCode to "0" in your project
            if (requestTelemetry.ResponseCode == "200")
            {
                // set Success property to false
                requestTelemetry.Success = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then register it in the `Startup.cs` -> `ConfigureServices` method:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {         
        //your other code

        //here, register the custom ITelemetryInitializer
        services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, MyTelemetryInitializer>();

    }
```

After executing the code, in azure portal -> your application insights -> Logs, you can see the Success property of request are made as false:

[image]